# In this particular case, the measure is the pmf, is my understanding right?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

wiki gives this [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_space) to illustrate measure space

set ${\displaystyle X=\{0,1\}}$

${\displaystyle {\mathcal {A}}={\mathcal {P}}(X)}$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$

the measure for this measure space ${\textstyle (X,{\mathcal {P}}(X),\mu )}$

is defined by ${\displaystyle \mu (\{1\})={\frac {1}{2}}, \mu (\{0\})={\frac {1}{2}}}$

it seems that measure $\mu$ (not just equal to) is the pmf of a Bernoulli distribution with ${\displaystyle p={\frac {1}{2}}}$

$f(k;0.5)={\begin{cases}0.5&{\text{if }}k=1,\\0.5&{\text{if }}k=0.\end{cases}}$

so, in this case, the measure is the pmf, is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.